# Show capacity of unplugged drive

Tags: macos, hard-drive, software-recommendation, disk-space

I have a lot of stored drives into my physical desktop and since I’m only using them on my own computer, I want to be able to keep an eye on the space left even if they’re not plugged in.

Do you guys know if there’s a software or a widget for macOS that can do this ?

Thank you

Majid

Comment: Um ... if they're not plugged in, macOS can't show you how much space is left. The bare drives themselves are sometimes labeled with the total capacity, but that's not what you want. I also don't really understand what "... stored drives _into_ my physical desktop..." actually means.

Comment: I assume he means actual, physical drawers in a desk. He probably wants to display the last known capacity left, which is a valid and possible thing to do.

Comment: Valid _once he plugs the drives in_ and checks the remaining space left and _notes the values in a document of some sort._ Please let me know how it is possible to 'keep an eye on the space left' on a drive which is not plugged in.